# HtAccess Rewrite Needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My host will not allow me to change the default folder of my primary domain.  I have managed to Rewrite http://www.mysite.com to the real folder

> public_html/mysite.com/www/

with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /mysite.com/www/ [R=301,L]
```

This does successfully load my domain from the subfolder, but the url becomes:

```
http://mysite.com/mysite.com/www/
```

How can I continue loading requests from http://mysite.com/index.html in the correct folder shown above, without showing it in the client-side url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/www/(.*)  - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/www/$1 [L]
```

UPD:

The line with the dash is required because after the redirect at line 3 Apache reads the .htaccess once again to process the redirected URL. The rule prevents infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, The suggestion from dreeves also worked but for some reason my images no longer worked.  This solution worked perfectly :-)

Comment: I'm glad to see the right solution to this.  Could you explain what that dash is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the R=301.